# Add Method not working in a many to many relationship

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have this many to many relationship between bus and driver .

This is the bus entity :

```
/**
     * @var ArrayCollection<Driver> The driver of this bus.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Driver", inversedBy="bus" , cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="bus_driver")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="driver_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * */
    private $driver;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->driver = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function addDriver($driver) {
        $this->driver[] = $driver;
        return $this;
    }
```

And this is the driver entity :

```
/**
     * @var ArrayCollection<Bus> The buses of this driver
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Bus", mappedBy="driver")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="bus_driver")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bus_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $bus;

public function __construct() {
        $this->bus = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
 public function addBus($bus) {
        $this->bus[] = $bus;
        $bus->addDriver($this);
        return $this;
    }
```

My problem is that when I add a bus with a driver the relation is persisted but not when I add a driver whih a bus . It works only from the bus side.

Answer (score 0):

please, consider renaming $driver into $drivers, as there is multiple drivers (same for bus -> buses)

and then you should try that:

@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="xxx", cascade={"persist"})

more details: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

Comment: To complete this answer, if you use ArrayCollection, use `add()` method to add an element to a Collection

Comment: I tried that but still not working , the addSomthings method is not triggered by the post action .
The only thing that worked is :

public function setDrivers($driver) {
        $this->driver = $driver;
        return $this;
    }
This only works on the owning side (Bus) .

Answer (score 0):

Change these (add the null and call it 'drivers'):

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
...
private $drivers = null;

public function __construct() {
  $this->drivers = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function addDriver($driver) {
  $this->drivers[] = $driver;
  return $this;
}
```

Also, to resolve the problem from the Bus Entity side, you might (but I'm not sure) need this change:

```
public function addDriver($driver) {
  $driver->addBus($this);
  $this->drivers[] = $driver;
  return $this;
}
```

Try it, since I have a similar scenario in a ManyToOne relation, and I'm wondering if the above change might work.

Comment: the add method doesn't seem to be triggered at all , it only works when i name it setDriver for example

Comment: check my answer :)) it worked for me for many to many and one to many

Answer (score 0):

The only working scenario was when I had :

A setter for the drivers collection .
An addDriver Method .
A removeDriver Method.

If I remove one of the pervious , addDriver won't even trigger at all .